# How to adding checked item from checkedlistbox to combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox, checkedlistbox

I want to adding checked item from checkedlistbox to my combobox, but i have a little problem here. Combobox only show 1 item last checked.
This is my sample code.

```
    If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count <> 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
            cbCheckedItem.Text = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(i).ToString
        Next i
    End If
```

anyone can help me show all checked item??
thank's for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough the CheckedListBox has a CheckedItems property, which is a collection. As such you can loop through it like you can any other collection, using a For or For Each loop.

then, Each item needs to be added to the Items collection of the ComboBox.

like this sample:

```
Public Class frmCheckedListBox

Private Sub frmCheckedListBox_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.CheckedListBox1.Items.Clear()
    Me.CheckedListBox1.BeginUpdate()
    Me.CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("One")
    Me.CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("Two")
    Me.CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("Three")
    Me.CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("Four")
    Me.CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("Five")
    Me.CheckedListBox1.EndUpdate()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each Item As String In Me.CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
        Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(Item)
        Me.ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

As sample code shows, the CheckedItems collection contains the items that are checked, just as the name suggests. It doesn't contain a Boolean value for each an every item to indicate whether it is checked or not. If an item is checked then that item is in the CheckedItems, and if it isn't then it isn't. You simply need to loop through the collection and get every item in it, because it contains all the items that are checked and none that aren't.

in the end you can put :

```
Me.Combobox1.items.clear()
```

because when it would click with sample code it would have the one that clicked then on the next click would return the previous one it had clicked and then the new one all compiled in the combobox selection menu

perhaps my answer can help you solve your problems

Comment: I'm puzzled as to why you posted an answer 5 days later that says the exact same thing mine does, and just as importantly, why it got 3 upvotes compared to 1 for me. Surely you should have upvoted my answer for giving you the idea of what code to post...

Comment: i think i dont need to upvote you. its basically my knowledge and not yours. lol

Answer (score 2):

You aren't *adding* the items to the combo box, you're only setting its `Text` property. That's *only* changing the text currently displayed in the combo box, and only one item can be displayed at a time.

If you want the items to be permanent and selectable, you need to *add* them to the combo box control's [`Items` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.items.aspx).

Sample code:

```
If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then
    For Each checkedItem In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
        cbCheckedItem.Items.Add(checkedItem.ToString())
    Next
End If
```

Or, better yet, use the [`AddRange` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange.aspx):

```
If CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then
    Dim checkedItems() As String = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Cast(Of String).ToArray()
    cbCheckedItems.Items.AddRange(checkedItems)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Combobox doesn't have a multiselect option. so only one item at a time could be selected.